# How to copy referenced images in css files to dist folder

Tags: html, css, gulp, assets

I'm having the following index.html file header:

```
<head>
<title>Visualization</title>
<!-- build:css styles/build.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.custom.min.css">
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/components/graph/graph.component.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/components/highchart/highchart.component.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/components/my-app/app.component.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The issue I'm facing right now is the following:

The file `../bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.custom.min.css` contains references to fonts and images.

```
bower_components
  bootstrap
    css
      bootstrap.custom.min.css
      i
        logo.png
    fonts
      glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
      glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
src
  index.html
```

I would like to write a bower script, that copies this files to the `dist` folder that I'm using to deploy my application including the actual hierarchy.

As I am having this issue a couple of times I would like to write a general (preferable gulp) task, that takes care of this.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a taskrunner to copy your files.
Here is a simple gulp setup to copy images, fonts and css from `bower_components` to your `dist` folder.
You may have to adjust the source and dist path.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('copy:css', function() {
  return gulp.src('./bower_components/path/to/css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/css'))
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./bower_components/path/to/fonts')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/fonts'))
});

gulp.task('copy:images', function() {
  return gulp.src('./bower_components/path/to/images')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/images'))
});
```

If you use multiple locations, you can use an array instead of a string for your source files.

```
gulp.task('copy:images', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    './bower_components/module1/path/to/images',
    './bower_components/module2/path/to/images'
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/images'))
});
```

To execute your script you run `gulp copy:css`, `gulp copy:fonts`, `gulp copy:images`

Comment: Well, as I said above, I know how to do it "manually", I would like to have a task that uses the references contained in a CSS file to fonts and images to copy these files automatically.

Comment: I just found `bower-files` https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-files. Looks like this does exactly what you are looking for.